# GoodData UI many requests

Tags: gooddata

I createad reports with GoodData UI and works successful.

GoodData UI exists many requests. In desktop OK but In mobile will use many 4G to customer.

Do exist control to requests ?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uab64.png)

---

Hi Ivan,

I used react [link](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/ht_create_your_first_visualization.html).

In image exists 856 request without to stop.

Code used:

```
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
        <Visualization
            identifier="abbAX8VdfTM8"
            projectId="dkrwpz8ki4iplckqups7luwz8uiviacy"
        />
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your question. I need more details about your use-case. Which SDK components do you use? What is in your react code in <>? , , or what? Second: from attached screenshot is not clear which xhr requests are fired, I can't see URI or name of requested resource so I am not sure if all these requests are going to GoodData platform or not. Please attach screenshot with details of one selected request and its Header

Comment: Hi Ivan. I eidited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the dependencies and worked successfully.

```
  "dependencies": {
     "@gooddata/react-components": "^6.1.1",
     "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
     "react": "^16.5.2",
     "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
     "react-scripts": "2.1.2" },
```